# Prove $\sqrt{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}\geq 2$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, contest-math

I want to show why the last inequality in the problem below $\sqrt{x^2+1} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2 +1}}\geq 2$ holds.  It's clear that $x^2\geq 0$ and that equality holds when $x=0$ but how can I clearly show this.  The left hand side, for $x^2>0$ is greater than $1$ but the right hand side becomes less than $1$ as $x^2>0$

---

[image]

Comment: Hint: think AM-GM, or any of several related ways.

Comment: I don't see how to use AM-GM here?

Comment: By AM-GM $\;\displaystyle \frac{\;a + \dfrac{1}{a}\;}{2} \ge \sqrt{a \cdot \frac{1}{a}} = 1\,$, then use it for $\,a=\sqrt{x^2+1}\,$.

Comment: This is very nice!

Comment: Also: [Proving an inequality involving square roots and polynomials $\frac{a^2+2}{\sqrt{a^2+1}}\ge2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2098346/proving-an-inequality-involving-square-roots-and-polynomials-fraca22-sqrt).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The inequality $(y-1)^{2} \geq 0$ gives $y+\frac 1 y \geq 2$ for any positive number $y$. Take $y=\sqrt {1+x^{2}}$.

Answer (score 2):

The derivative of $f(y)=y+1/y$ is $1-1/y^2$,  so the function $f$ increases in $[1,\infty)$, hence $f(y)\geq f(1)=2$.

Comment: `f increases in [1,∞)`,And also decreases on $[0,1]$ which is needed to complete the argument.

Comment: @dxiv - Since $\sqrt{x^2+1}\geq 1$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, the interval $[0,1]$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Right, but that belongs in the answer, not a comment.

Comment: Feel free to include this in your answer.

Comment: I didn't post an answer. Feel free to spell it out in *your* answer.